# POST application/x-www-form-urlencoded Body to REST API using Jitterbit

Tags: jitterbit, x-www-form-urlencoded

I know I've done this before, but I'm spacing on how to properly do it, now.

I'm trying to call the Paylocity token API.  Doing it with cURL and Postman works just fine.  But, I can't remember how to send the body properly in Jitterbit.  This is the cURL info that I'm trying to send, but it does not get the payload data, and always returns the invalid grant type error.

The --data-urlencode piece is what I'm failing to remember.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.paylocity.com/IdentityServer/connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic XXXXX=' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=WebLinkAPI'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

George Jeffcock pointed me in the right direction.  The issue was the extra line breaks.  This link notes that.

https://community.jitterbit.com/s/question/0D54X0000687kiZSAQ